# How to define trunk port between vmware esxi host 6.5 and switch?

Tags: vlan, trunk, vmware, virtual

I create some virtual machine in different vlan but i can not set trunk port from vmware to transfer vlan information.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server/VM configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the ESXi side, assign a VLAN ID to the port group you want tagged. A port group without VLAN ID goes untagged.

On the physical switch side, create a trunk and assign VLANs as tagged and untagged as required (max. 1 VLAN untagged).

Comment: Thanks, for helping me again.
I had done it before, but I wasn't sure. I just had to wait a little longer.